# ruby on rails ActionMailer error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use ActionMailer for the first time.

My mailer looks like this:

```
class RequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "fred@ameipro.com"
 def request_email(worequest)
 @worequest = worequest
 mail(:to => "dave@ameipro.com", :subject => "New Service Request")
 end
end
```

But, I get the following error:
    Net::SMTPFatalError in WorequestsController#create

```
550 Cannot receive from specified address <fred@ameipro.com>:     Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

How do I correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from the mail server - it is refusing to deliver email from your address. Thats the part you need to diagnose.  To help you, we'd need more information about the server you're trying to send through.  To troubleshoot, I would try configuring a different client to send through your server, then try to send an email from fred@ameipro.com to dave@ameipro.com and see what happens.